ECC Point addition implementation in cpp
I have a c++ code snippet that produces a point that is the result of R = P + Q using SECP256K1's parameters, yet for some reason, the values i recieve are incorrect.
This is the code:
Point* KeyGenerator::ECAdd(Point* pnt1, Point* pnt2) {
    if (pnt1->is_infinity()) return pnt2;
    if (pnt2->is_infinity()) return pnt1;
    if (pnt1->_x == pnt2->_x && pnt1->_y != pnt2->_y) return new Point(0, 0);

    int256_t deltaY = (pnt2->_y - pnt1->_y) % PCurve;
    int256_t deltaX = (pnt2->_x - pnt1->_x) % PCurve;

    if (deltaX < 0) {
        deltaX += PCurve;
    }

    int256_t lambda = (deltaY * mod_inverse(deltaX, PCurve)) % PCurve;

    if (lambda < 0) {
        lambda += PCurve;
    }

    int256_t x3 = (lambda * lambda - pnt1->_x - pnt2->_x) % PCurve;
    if (x3 < 0) {
        x3 += PCurve;
    }

    int256_t y3 = (lambda * (pnt1->_x - x3) - pnt1->_y) % PCurve;
    if (y3 < 0) {
        y3 += PCurve;
    }

    return new Point(x3, y3);
}

This is using Boosts precision 256 bit integers, and their modulo inverse

The sum of two 256-bit integers is sometime 257-bit; and their product sometime is 512-bit.

so should i just use bigger numbers? like int512_t just to compensate for those cases?

This is odd then, I am trying to test my answers against a test vector, yet my answers are wrong, im currently testing just the addition, yet i still get incorrect values

[Revision of my earlier comments] Yes, as far as I can tell by proofreading, with int512_t (which correctly represents $[1-2^{512},2^{512}-1]$ you'd get the correct result for most inputs. But this is not the only goal worth pursuing in cryptography; there are also correctness, side-channel resistance, speed, self-containedness, and elegance. On correctness: deltaX can be zero. As an aside it's silently assumed input coordinates are in range $[0,\mathsf{PCurve}-1]$.

Alright, so the main issue was using modulo after EVERY calculation, which reset the values very often, by only adding the % Pcurve within the lambda calculation i got the values correct
